# Shift current datetime in GBQ

Tags: function, timestamp, google-bigquery, shift

Does anyone know how to shift unix timestamp in GBQ to minute (e.g. How to simulate function UTC_USEC_TO_MINUTE)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can just floor the value with modulo? Is there something else you want here?

Comment: @Pentium10, this is all I needed. It was there all the time but I've not seen it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just floor the value with modulo.